# Excel VBA Open Read-Only when File is in Use

Tags: vba, excel

I have some VBA code in an Excel workbook that opens another workbook just to copy and paste some cells back into the first workbook. Therefore, I only need to open it read-only.
 The current line of code:
 `Workbooks.Open Filename:=qBDARsvFile, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False` 
 
 If someone else is currently in the file, I get an error. I thought the `ReadOnly:=True` part of the code would allow the workbook to be opened still. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `Notify:= True`, see the [workbooks.open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) language reference.

> **Notify**
>
> If the file cannot be opened in read/write mode, this argument is True
>   to add the file to the file notification list. Microsoft Excel will
>   open the file as read-only, poll the file notification list, and then
>   notify the user when the file becomes available. **If this argument is
>   False or omitted, no notification is requested, and any attempts to
>   open an unavailable file will fail.**

(Emphasis mine)

This should allow you to open the file, read your cells and then close it again, even if it is already in-use.